# My Ubuntu does see my 5Ghz network

Tags: wireless

I searched the Ubuntu site but each answer is relate to a specific network card.

I ran the Ubuntu script to gather all network information. Where do I upload this zip file?

Comment: What is your question? What zipfile do you want to upload and where?

Comment: What network card do you have?  Maybe it doesn't do 5GHz.

Comment: If someone gave you a script to create a zip file with details, you'll have to find the **site** and **message** that gave you the script and proceed with them.  On this site, if you have questions, you'll need to provide enough information in your question so that the users can access the problem.  You are probably saying, by the way, "Your Ubuntu does not see your 5Ghz network"... which should be in the form of a question.  A response to the other comments is important for us to be able to help.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu over my Gentoo flavor on my laptop. My Gentoo was seeing my 5Ghz Wifi network without problem, but Ubuntu doesn't see it.

Comment: My Wifi network card is Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
While searching the internet, I found a thread on "Ask Ubuntu" that was suggesting running a Ubuntu script that grab all the network information into a zip file that I should send back to the support team. I cannot find any link to upload my zip file